# Why is SVM unable to separate linearly separable data?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, algorithm, machine-learning

I have two sets of data, namely blue and yellow. I manually added a point `{8, -3}` to the blue data.

```
sampledata[center_] := BlockRandom[SeedRandom[123]; RandomVariate[MultinormalDistribution[center, IdentityMatrix[2]], 200]];
clusters1 = sampledata /@ {{9, 0}, {-9, 0}};
clusters1[[2]] = Append[clusters1[[2]], {8, -3}];

plot1 = ListPlot[clusters1, PlotStyle -> Darker@{Yellow, Blue}];
plot2 = Plot[0.2 - 0.375*x, {x, -12, 12}, PlotStyle -> Red];
Show[plot1, plot2]
```

[image]

As you can see, the two sets are linearly separable. Thus the SVM algorithm should be able to separate all points by using just a linear kernel. Now I try below:-

```
c3 = Classify[<|Yellow -> clusters1[[1]], Blue -> clusters1[[2]]|>, Method -> {"SupportVectorMachine", "KernelType" -> "Linear"}]
Show[Plot3D[{c3[{x, y}, "Probability" -> Yellow], c3[{x, y}, "Probability" -> Blue]}, {x, -15, 15}, {y, -4, 4}, Exclusions -> None], ListPointPlot3D[Map[Append[#, 1] &, clusters1, {2}], PlotStyle -> {Yellow, Blue}]]
```

[image]

As you can see, SVM failed to separate the points. The blue point `{8, -3}` is now located in the yellow region. Why would SVM be failed to separate the linearly separable points?

Many thanks!

Comment: Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31066/what-is-the-influence-of-c-in-svms-with-linear-kernel

Comment: @Niki Estner Thanks. In fact I tried something like `Method -> {"SupportVectorMachine", "KernelType" -> "Linear", "L2Regularization" -> 0.5}`in `Classify`, but got errors...

Comment: I think you are using a hard margin classifier. That means that no misclassified data points are allowed and as result the margin can get arbitrary crappy in the strife to make sure that exactly all data points are classified correctly.

Comment: Please don't use JPG for non-photographic images!

Comment: Wait I see now I misread your question, what I meant to say is that you have a soft margin classifier and you need to reduce the "softness" parameter. But I see you already know this from your answers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's not explicitly documented, but I think Mathematica is using the C-SVM variant, where a regularization parameter C basically says how "expensive" mislabeled training samples are, compared to the size of the margin. So in your case, SVM will perfer a larger margin between the yellow and the blue points. In 99% of the cases, this kind of robust behavor is exactly what you want.

If you don't want that, you can play with the (undocumented) `SoftMarginParameter` option. Think of this as the cost of mislabeling a training sample, compared to getting a larger separation margin:

```
c3 = Classify[<|Yellow -> clusters1[[1]], Blue -> clusters1[[2]]|>, 
  Method -> {"SupportVectorMachine", "KernelType" -> "Linear", 
    "SoftMarginParameter" -> 1000000}]

Show[ContourPlot[
  c3[{x, y}, "Probability" -> Yellow], {x, -15, 15}, {y, -4, 4}, 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic], plot1]
```

[image]

Now all samples are classified "correctly", but if you tried the classifier on new data, it will likely perform worse, as some of the dots are much closer to the margin

Comment: As to why it would be likely to perform worse... Consider the likelihood of the outlier point being a true member of one or another distribution. Chances of any point being as far or further from the blue cluster with its distribution are about 2 * 10^-65, while from the yellowish cluster the chances are around 7 * 10^-3.

Comment: @kirma not necessarily, if we dont know the distribution the blue one could well be a sum of monomodal distributions where the second mode is really really close to the yellow cluster. For example sum of two gaussians where the big cluster has samples 100 or 1000 times as often as the "outlier".

Comment: @mathreadler Sure, we can't be sure. Nonetheless it is in my opinion much more sensible to find a trade-off which reduces chances of wrong classifications in an obvious area of risk than speculate about something which is practically unknown.

Comment: @kirma I think mathreadler's point is exactly that... When giving these numbers you are speculating yourself ;)

Comment: @sebhofer Well... In this particular case we actually know that data originates, apart from one point, from specific distributions. Of course it's more complicated with real data, but quite often (multi)normal distribution is a good starting assumption for a fit, or at least it's convenient to work with. There's a tuning parameter for the task, but it might out turn into a gun pointing on ones' own foot.

Comment: It is quite often in real life that data is much more complicated than monomodal. The probability distribution over locations for getting drunk for example are probably sum of different distributions over a citys bars and friends places. If you are drunk 10 times in Bar A and then 1 time at Bar B you could claim that bar B is an outlier. But maybe it's just the rare instances when you meet a friend who is rarely in town.

Comment: @mathreadler: All true, but in real life, you often can't make perfect classifications, you just don't have enough data. In that case, it's often better to label "Bar B" as an outlier and make good predictions 9 times out of 10 instead of treating it as an inlier and get 7 good predictions in 10.

Comment: @NikiEstner Yes, often. And that is why soft margin machines were introduced.